# iOS8 launch screen with pattern background

Tags: ios8

How can i create a launch screen with a background pattern image in ios8, without violating any of the rules reported by Apple documentation on "Creating a Launch screen"?

The documentation says: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW3)

- Use only UIKit classes.
- Use a single root view that is a UIView or UIViewController object. Don’t make any connections to your code  (don’t add actions or outlets).
- Don’t add UIWebView objects.
- Don’t use any custom classes.
- Don’t use runtime attributes.

I think that I'm not the only one who may need a "responsive" launch screen like this

[image]

but as i know it's not possibile to set the background pattern from a xib/storyboard.